# How do you allow an ActiveX object to install an updated version before instantiating it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, activex

Our clients all have a 6.11 version of our ActiveX control installed. With the new version of our software, we'll have a 7.00 version that includes some new functionality. Now if a user were to go to a special "update only" page with an `<OBJECT>` tag on it, they'll be prompted to install the software, and the update will install without any issue.

However, that would be a big change to our current set up and client expectations. What the client expects is to upgrade to the newer software and immediately make use of the software pages that instantiate the ActiveX object and provide functionality. On some of these pages, the JavaScript that uses the object does not run immediately (i.e. triggered by the body onload event.) In these cases, the ActiveX control updates to the newer version.

But on pages that try to use the object, somehow the update does not succeed. The dialog to install the software comes up, and the JavaScript does not fire until after that. But somehow it's blocked. Is there some way to configure the code so that the object successfully updates, and then afterwards, the JavaScript can fire up and use the (updated) object with the new functionality?

```
<html>
<head><script>window.onload = function() { obj.DoNewThing(); }</script></head>
<body>
<object id="obj" classid="CLSID:AA4123A4-A567-890A-AA12-3AA4A56A7A8A" codebase="/controls/obj.cab#Version=7,0,0,0"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue was not, in fact, that JavaScript was instantiating the object. Rather, I believe Internet Explorer (I'm using an 11.x version) prevents update of add-ons from a pop-up window, but allows it when initiated from the main browser window.